# Rotating A Single View in Portrait App

Tags: ios, iphone, rotation

I am making an app which is in portrait mode only. But contains graph view in it and I want the graph view in both directions Portrait and Landscape. I have tried many methods given on the different posts but I am not able to rotate it. I am using iOS 6. Any help will be appreciated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My app also support only portrait orientation but for one view i am providing portrait as well as landscape orientation.

You will need to access view's layer and rotate it manually.
Add following code and call it from orientation delegate method
 `- (void) didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification`

Here is code..

```
- (void) rotateViewToOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{ 
    CALayer *viewLayer = // assign view layer here.

    switch (interfaceOrientation)
    {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        {
            viewLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            break;
        }
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        {
            viewLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(180.0 / 180.0 * M_PI, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            break;
        }
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        {
            viewLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(90.0 / 180.0 * M_PI, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

            break;
        }
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        {
            viewLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(270.0 / 180.0 * M_PI, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Set frames as per requirement after transforming.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your target settings should look like this:

[image: Supported Interface Orientations]

In UITabBarController:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // You do not need this method if you are not supporting earlier iOS Versions
    return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if (self.selectedViewController) 
    return [self.selectedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

Inside your ViewController:

a) if you dont want to rotate:

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
     return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }

 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
 {
     return NO;
 }

 - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
 {
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
 }
```

b) if you want to rotate to landscape:

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
   return YES;
 }

 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
 {
      return YES;
 }

 - (NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
 {
      return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
 }
```

Other solution is to implement this method inside AppDelegate:

```
 - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
 {
      NSUInteger orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

     if (self.window.rootViewController) {
         UIViewController* presented = [[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers] lastObject];
         orientations = [presented supportedInterfaceOrientations];
     }

     return orientations; 
 }
```

Comment: I am not using tabbar controller...

Comment: and I have only portrait in settings

Comment: ok thwn also try with above code

Comment: This is not working for me